# Efficient way to select data with a single condition

Tags: java, sql, arrays, database, select

Is there an efficient way to obtain a list (preferably an array, a `ResultSet` will do) to `SELECT` a lot of rows.

For example:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,username,password);
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE food = ? AND expiration > ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Using the above code, I want to get all the food from a given array that isn't expired.

```
String[] foodList  = {"banana","apple","orange",...}
```

where the expiration date is a constant date (lets say 3 days ago). However, the way I have it is that the String and PreparedStatement are in a for loop that loop the number of foods in the array to individually check the expiration date. This creates a lot of `ResultSet`s after I execute each individually.

Comment: Do you need each result individually ? If not, why not to use **select blah blah where food IN (" + list + ") and expiration > ?**

Comment: I was trying to grab all the food that wasnt expired @eckes

Comment: @alp i actually don't need them individually and I will look into using `in`
edit: sean bright showed me how i would use `in` in this case

Comment: @Brian please check documentation. There might be a performance payback. I don't remember if IN uses indexes or not. If you go with that route and use IN, make sure to confirm it does.

Comment: @alp Thanks! I've read that IN is somewhat faster

Comment: For Oracle a `IN` is rewritten to an `OR` internally, and it will use an index if there is one (as long as you not use transformation functions like `toUpper`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most SQL Databases support a `IN (list)` expression. This is roughly equivalent to providing a or expression:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE food IN ('Apple', 'Banana')  AND exp < ?
```

is similar to

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE (food = 'Apple' or food = 'Banana') AND exp < ?
```

In both cases some RDBMS can optimize it.

However first of all there is a limitation in the number of list items you can specify in the IN or number of characters you can use in the statement. So if your list can be variable long you need to be prepared to run multiple statements.

Secondly you cannot* set a array as an argument to a `PreparedStatement` and expect it to work with IN.

Unfortunately in plain JDBC all you can do is to concatenate a String. This is frowned upon, but there is no good alternative (unless you want to do something like giving the list of foods as a single list and use a "instring" expression).

Make sure to add as many `?` (but not too many) as you expect parameters and then set them in the `IN`:

```
String[] foods = ...;
int remain = foods.length;
int start = 0;
while(remain > 0)
{  if (remain >= 100)
     executeBatch(foods, start, 100); start+=100; remain-=100;
   else if (remain >= 30)
     executeBatch(foods, start, 30); start+=30; remain-=30;
   else {
     executeBatch(foods, start, 1); start+=1; remain-=1;
   }
}


void executeBatch(String[] f, int off, int len)
{
    StringBuilder sqlBuf = StringBuilder("... IN(");
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        sqlBuf.append((i!=0)?",?":"?");
    }
    String sql = sqlBuf.append(") AND exp < ?").toString();
    PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
    for(int i=0;i<foods.length;i++)
        ps.setString(i+1, foods[i+off]);
    ps.setTimestamp(foods.length+1, now);
    ....
}
```

This avoids to generate a lot of different SQL statement to compile. (Only 100,30 or 1 ?)). You can use the same logic for the OR case.

<sup>* not to be confused with ARRAY database type.</sup>

Comment: superb approach ... but i have one doubt .. why did you break the above logic in to 100,30,1  instead of directly going from 0 to food.lenght()... can you pleas explain this?..

Comment: If you have a large number of batches with different length then each of them will be a new SQL statement resulting in a hard parse on the Oracle side. If you have only a few selected argument-numbers (3 in my example) they will get cached and soft parsed. So you lower the SQL area pollution. It does not matter if you do this seldom or the variance is small (or constant).

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most elegant solution, and you won't get any performance benefit from the prepared statement (but you will get parameter binding):

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE expiration > ? AND food IN (");

for (int i = 0; i < foodList.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        sql.append(',');
    }
    sql.append('?');
}

sql.append(")");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

stmt.setDate(1, expirationDate);
for (int i = 0; i < foodList.length; i++) {
    stmt.setString(i + 2, foodList[i]);
}

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

/* ... Do Stuff ... */
```